# Want to animate splash screen on Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to add fade in and fade out to a splash screen after a few seconds of loading. Is there a sample for doing this to my splash layout?

Comment: You need your questions / answers to be voted up to gain reputation (5 per question +1, 10 per answer +1), I just +1ed you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an example of slow transition between activities. You can add your own animation:

```
public class OneActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(OneActivity.this, TwoActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**slide_in_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

**slide_out_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**Fade in and fade out effects:**

```
<!-- Fade out -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:duration="300" />

<!-- Fade in -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="300" />

<!-- Slide in right and slide out right  -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Also take a look on *[Splash Fade, Activity Animations, overridePendingTransition](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/splash-fade-activity-animations-overridependingtransition-t9464.html)*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add an animation to an activity, a view and so on...

Check the post *[Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)* to get the idea to apply animation.